# gdal_retile.py tile naming scheme

Tags: gdal

Is there a way to define custom tile names during a gdal_retile.py process, other than the default _01_01. For instance, suppose I want to start naming my tiles at 100_100, is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@algone, if you're comfortable editing the utility's `gdal_retile.py` Python file, open it, and find where the `getTileName()` method is defined.

In my version, it appears at line #652 and looks like this:

`def getTileName(minfo,ti,xIndex,yIndex,level = -1):`

To accommodate what you're wanting to do, I can merely override the `xIndex` and `yIndex` values as follows (I'm showing only a portion of that method for some context, note the "ADD THIS" comments):

```
def getTileName(minfo,ti,xIndex,yIndex,level = -1):
    """
    creates the tile file name
    """
    global LastRowIndx

    xIndex += 100    # ADD THIS, where 100 is your preferred starting value
    yIndex += 100    # AND THIS, ditto

    max = ti.countTilesX
    if (ti.countTilesY > max):
        max=ti.countTilesY
    countDigits= len(str(max))
    # ..
    # .. shortened for brevity
    # ..
```

I tested it, and it did what you're wanting, basically calling the utility like this:

`gdal_retile.py "D:\GIS\LongPathToData\jasper_nw.tif" -v -of png -ps 512 512 -r cubic -tileIndex test -levels 8 -targetDir "D:\GIS\LongPathToData\test2" -useDirForEachRow`

Comment: Thanks a heap! that worked like charm. I only changed it abit to enable user to define additional startRowNum and startColNum parameters